# How to get multiple rows from database to form an XML?

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jaxb

I am using JAXB for creating an XML file.

By using the below code, I am able to create an XML but the problem is that I need to get data from database in a object which may have multiple rows so the XML should include multiple iterations of the same.

I couldn't find a suitable approach.

```
try {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/jos/Desktop/Project/jaxb/xml/newfile.xml");
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Info.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);


    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(info, file);

 } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: What exception are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are wanting is a list of Info objects right?

```
[ListOfInfo]
    [Info]1[/Info]
    [Info]2[/Info]
    [Info>3[/Info]
[/ListOfObject]
```

So you need to model your Java classes as this
I.e topLevel ListOfInfo class that has a collection of Info objects.